# Como alterar o resultado da requisição de uma API Rest com Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, rest

Eai guys, tudo bem? Comecei estudar Spring recentemente por conta própria e estou tentando criar uma API Rest para cadastro de alunos e provas em uma escola.

#### Estou com o seguinte problema:

Quando eu faço uma requisição GET para listar todos os alunos cadastrados no banco, retorna um json gigante como esse:

> localhost:8080/api/alunos

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
    "nome" : "Carlos Eduardo Ribeiro",
    "media" : 0.0,
    "provas" : [{
        "id" : 1,
        "nota" : 0.0,
        "aluno" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "nome": "Carlos Eduardo Ribeiro",
            "media" : 0.0,
            "provas" : [{
                "id" : 1,
                "nota" : 0.0,
                "aluno" : {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "nome" : "Carlos Eduardo Ribeiro",
                    "media": 0.0,
                    "provas": [{
                        "id" : 1,
                        "nota" : 0.0,
                        "aluno" : {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "nome":"Carlos Eduardo Ribeiro",
                            "media":0.0,
                            "provas": [{
                                ......
                                    ......
                                        ......
```

Aqui está os models: 
*Aluno.java*

```
@Entity(name = "aluno")
public class Aluno {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float media;

    // Um aluno contem uma lista de Provas:
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aluno")
    private List<Prova> provas;

    // Construtor
    public Aluno() {
        this.setMedia(0.0f);
    }

    // Getters | Setters
    
}
```

*Prova.java*

```
@Entity
public class Prova {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float nota;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_aluno")
    private Aluno aluno;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prova")
    private List<Questao> questoes;


    // Contrutor:
    public Prova() {
        this.setNota(0.0f); // define a nota padrão
    }

    // Getters | Setters
    
}
```

Aqui está o Controller:
*AlunoController.java*

```
@RestController
public class AlunoController {

    @Autowired
    private AlunosRepository repository;

    // Faz uma consulta pelo id do aluno:
    @GetMapping(path = "/api/aluno/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity consultar(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id) {
        // Faz e retorna a consulta:
        return this.repository.findById(id)
                .map(record -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(record))    // Monta e retorna o ResponseBody com o registro
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());         // Caso contrário retorna um notFound
    }

    // Cadastra um novo aluno:
    @PostMapping(path = "/api/aluno/cadastrar")
    public Aluno cadastrar(@RequestBody Aluno aluno) {
        return this.repository.save(aluno); // Cadastra o aluno recebido no RequestBody e retorna
    }

    // Retorna todos os alunos cadastrados:
    @GetMapping(path = "/api/alunos")
    public List<Aluno> consultarAlunos() {
        return this.repository.findAll();
    }

}
```

#### Tentei fazer:

Tentei alterar o método consultarAlunos() para percorrer os registros com um foreach e ir atribuindo null ao objeto aluno da entidade Prova e funcionou, porém, eu não quero que o resultado retorne o "aluno" dentro de cada prova na lista.
O método ficou assim:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/alunos")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Aluno> consultarAlunos() {

    List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>(); // Cria uma lista para receber o resultado da request
    List<Prova> provas = new ArrayList<>(); // Array list para armazenas as provas sem o objeto aluno.

    // Percorre a lista de alunos:
    for ( Aluno aluno : this.repository.findAll() ) {

        // percorre a lista de provas do aluno:
        for( Prova prova : aluno.getProvas() ) {
            prova.setAluno(null);   // O objeto aluno não precisa ser especificado mais de uma vez.
            provas.add(prova);
        }

        aluno.setProvas(provas);
        alunos.add(aluno);

    }

    return new ResponseEntity(alunos, HttpStatus.OK);   // Cria e retorna os resultados.
}
```

resultado:

> localhost:8080/api/alunos

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
"nome" : "Carlos Eduardo Ribeiro",
        "media" : 0.0,
    "provas" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "nota" : 0.0,
            "aluno" : null,
            "questoes" : []
        }
    ]
}]
```

Como eu faço para obter um resultado parecido com o acima, porém no lugar do *"aluno" : null* eu obter o id relacionado a prova?
Obrigado.

Comment: Uma sugestão seria no método consultarAlunos utilizar como retorno um DTO e customizar as informações de retorno conforme a sua necessidade e futuramente até adicionar uma paginação nesse método também. Aqui tem uma explicação legal de DTO: https://medium.com/@msealvial/blindando-sua-api-spring-boot-com-o-padr%C3%A3o-dto-44f97020d1a0

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, já estou as classes DTO.
Em relação ao problema a cima, resolvi ele adicionando um @JsonIgnore na propriedade aluno da entidade Prova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido adicionando `@JsonIgnore` na propriedade `aluno` da entidade `Prova`. O codigo ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "id_aluno")
private Aluno aluno;
```

O resultado foi:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Carlos Eduardo Ribeiro",
        "media": 0.0,
        "provas": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "nota": 0.0
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nota": 0.0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```